# How to print a whole pair by just a key value in map c++?

Tags: c++

Let's say I'm having a map of integer key value!

```
map<int,string>a={{1,"one"},{2,"two"}};
```

How can I print a whole pair by just supplying a key value?

Let's say user entered 1; I want my code to print 1,one then,How can i do so?

Comment: Hint: You already know the key, print the value.

Comment: Check if the key value can be found in the map,  and if so just do `cout << key << ", " << a[key] << endl;`

Comment: Actually,Let me explain my full task, I've a map and user has to supply a key value,If that key value is present in that map,Then I've add that whole "pair" in different map,Is it possible to do so? I mean additing a whole pair

Comment: adding a whole pair from one map to another?

Comment: @ManavRoy If you want to supply updates to the question, [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) instead of writing them as comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've a map and user has to supply a key value,If that key value is present in that map,Then I've add that whole "pair" in different map, **Is it possible to do so**?

Yes this is possible. You can use `std::map::find` to check if your input map contains a given key and then `std::map::insert` to add the key value pair into the output map as shown below:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<int,string> searchMap={{1,"one"},{2,"two"}}; //map in which key is to be searched 
    
    std::map<int, string> outputMap;
    
    int input =0; 
    if(std::cin >> input); //take input from user 
    {
        //search the map for the input key 
        auto findInput = searchMap.find(input);
        if(findInput!=searchMap.end())//check if the input was found inside the map 
        {
            std::cout << "The map contains the key: " << input << " entered by user" << std::endl;
            //add the key value pair to the outputmap 
            outputMap.insert({input,findInput->second});  //or just outputmap[input] = findInput->second
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout <<"The map does not contain the key: " << input << " entered by user" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    
    //lets confirm that outputmap was filled with input 
    for(const auto&[key, value]:outputMap)
    {
        std::cout << key << "->" << value << std::endl;
    }
    
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/OgZNKkO1r)

Comment: @ManavRoy You're welcome :) If I may, i would also recommend using any of the books listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). They're also available as PDFs for free.

Comment: Sure,Thanks for the reccomadation:)) But i prefer yt tutorials and website's more as they do not consume much time,XD

Comment: @ManavRoy But keep in mind that this doesn't come for free - most of those tutorials and websites are created by non-professional programmers and teach how to write really bad and buggy code.